# Problemas para traer los elementos de una <ul>

Tags: javascript, dom

Quiero hacer un sorteo digital, y aunque el problema ya lo resolví necesito despejar una duda..
Tengo una lista desordenada cargada estáticamente en el html con una clase la cual utilizo luego para identificarla desde el módulo js. El problema surge cuando quiero obtener los valores de los elementos hijos de la misma. El ejercicio lo resolví con un Math.random(); y, si pongo el índice de un elemento en particular si me lo trae pero de ninguna manera pude traerlos todos.. siempre me imprime en consola undefined.
Aquí mi código:

```
//html..
  <ul class="list-of-names">
          <li>Carlos</li>
          <li>Andrés</li>
          <li>Tamara</li>
          <li>Leonel</li>
          <li>Pablo</li>
          <li>Lucía</li>
          <li>Margot</li>
          <li>Federico</li>
          <li>Romina</li>
          <li>Fausto</li>
          <li>German</li>
        </ul>
        <button id="btn-draw">Obtener Ganador</button>
```

Este es el módulo que contiene la función que realiza el sorteo:

```
const d = document;

export default function digitalDraw(btn, list) {
  d.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.matches(btn)) {
      /* const $btn = d.getElementById(btn); */
      const listOfNames = d.querySelector(list);
      let names = listOfNames.getElementsByTagName("li");
      let numero = names.length;
      let winner = Math.floor(Math.random() * numero);
      console.log(names.length);
      console.log(winner);
      console.log(names.textContent);
      console.log(`El ganador/a del sorteo es ${names[winner].textContent}`);
    }
  });
}
```

Y por último el archivo principal, desde el cual se invocan las diferentes funciones:

```
import digitalDraw from "./Digital_Draw/digitalDraw.js";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
    digitalDraw("#btn-draw", ".list-of-names")
}
```

El tercer console.log() es el que me trae undefined.. Por qué?

Comment: `names` es un objeto por lo tanto no puedes acceder así por así si quieres comprobarlo pon esto `console.log(names[0].textContent)` veraz que si entra  a la propiedad y trae el nombre, tendrás que iterarlo de alguna forma.

Comment: En ese console.log quieres traer el nombre de todos los `li`?

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux exacto.. igual el ejercicio está resuelto..pero tenia esa duda